# Running Same Junit test multiple times with different parameters

Tags: java, junit, parameters

I have a JUnit test which is based on numeric calculations, which needs to be run 5 times, each with a different input from a JSON file. The tests also will read configuration data from a common config file.

One of the parameters in the common config file is `whichTestsTobeRun: [1, 4, 5]`, which is used to specify which tests are to be run. The common config file also some other parameters like whether to generate a log file.

What I would like to do is:
1. Read parameters from the common config
2. Read the test specific JSON file and then run the tests based on those input parameters

Could someone please guide me how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As you've already pointed to [parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests) in JUnit I'd go for them. Something like the following should do what you want (taken and adapted from the provided link).

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FooTest {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<TestData> data() {
        Collection<TestData> dataCollection = loadFromSource();
        return dataCollection ;
    }

    private TestData data; // contains input and expected output

    public FooTest(TestData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        assertEquals(data.someExpectedValue, foo.execute(data.jsonConfig));
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** not compiled nor tested.